# RegexValidator doesn't work on CharField

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I use python 3.5 and django 1.10. For my form I use crispy-forms.
My form:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(
    max_length=140,
    widget=forms.Textarea,
    validators=[
        RegexValidator(
            r"^[A-Za-z\s]*$",
            message='You must use english language!',
            code='invalid_language'),
    ]
)
```

My view:

```
 def myview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        action = request.POST.get('action')
        shift = request.POST.get('shift')
        input = request.POST.get('input')

        if action == 'encrypt':
            output = encrypt(input, shift)
        else:
            output = decrypt(input, shift)
        return render(request, 'myapp/base.html',
            {'form': form, 'output': output})
```

When I post my form (with non-valid input) I get

> ValueError at /myview
>   The view myapp.views.myview didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Why don't I get my message from validator?

Comment: Can you post the entire view? It's clearly missing things that are needed to answer your question. It has nothing to do with the validator itself.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: You have a return statement inside the if clause of your view, but no return otherwise. As stated by the error you posted, you are not returning an HttpResponse object. That only happens in the case of the form being invalid. Add a return outside the if clause and you should see the behavior you expect.

Comment: It helped. Thank you.

Comment: What do you hope to happen if the form isn't valid? (which it currently isn't), you need to unindent your return statement